# Change Width/Height of SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash, swfobject

I'm trying to edit an HTML that uses swfobject to load a flash file.

What I'm trying to do is to reduce the size of the SWF file.

I've tried editing the height and width parameter within the swfobject(), but that didn't work.

I tried reducing the width height in the HTML css, but that also didn't work..

How can I pass a 'width' or a 'height' parameter to the swfobject so it will actually load the swf in a smaller or 'zoomed out' way?

Thanks,

Comment: on load of the swf scale the application to fit the container that it is loaded in.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of swfobject, and which embed method you are using it may vary slightly, but in general a call to swfobject.embedSWF looks like this:

```
swfobject.embedSWF(   "myMovie.swf", 
                      "divIdToReplace", 
                      "100%", 
                      "900", 
                      "9.0.0",
                      "expressInstall.swf", 
                      flashvars, params, attributes
                  );
```

In this example I have set my width to 100% and my height to 900 pixels.  If you are doing the embed in another way, post some code and perhaps I can help.

** NOTE **
Just because you can resize the container doesn't automatically mean you can "zoom out" on the swf.  If the swf has "no scale" set, then instead of zooming out, you will just be cropping the swf.

** **EDIT** **
You can try setting the params object to include scale:"default", like this for example:

```
var params = {
            menu: "false",
            salign: "LT",
            scale: "default",
            quality: "high"
};
```

This is the `params` object you would pass into `embedSWF` like I have shown above.

Comment: I've tried changing the values on swfobject and as you say it just crops the SWF. Is it possible to override the no scale? where is it defined?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm embedding the swf exactly as you wrote above. But changing the height/width crops the SWF as you said it might would. Is it possible to override the 'no scale' in some way? Where is it defined?

Comment: It is defined in the SWF itself, but you can override it in the embed tag.  See updated answer above.

Comment: tried this, still cropping the container instead of changing the width of the SWF.. any other ideas?

Comment: It's possible that you are overriding the scale type from the AS3 code in the SWF--especially possible if you are using any engines such as Flixel or Flashpunk. See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode

Comment: @31eee384 can you please explain a bit more? I'm really unfamiliar with Flash so it's very difficult for me to understand whats described in the url you provided.

Comment: Well, I think a first important question is this: are you the author of the SWF file? If not, my suggestion is basically worthless. If so, then what I'm suggesting is that you may have inadvertently set the scale mode to something other than default within the code, _after_ the SWF has been loaded. This would show up somewhere as `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.[any of the choices from the doc]`. See the bottom of the doc page for an example. I've only used the variable once myself, so I don't know if it would completely override the html like that, but it's a place to look.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a container/wrapper for the SWF, set the width/height of the SWF to be 100%, then scale the container to whatever size you desire. This is covered in an older Stack Overflow post: [Resize an SWF when loading it with SWFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952732/resize-an-swf-when-loading-it-with-swfobject)

Additional examples for using SWFObject and 100% scaling:
http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/100-width-and-height-in-browser/