# SWFObject 2.0 Dynamic Scaling

Tags: flash, dynamic, scale, swfobject

I'm trying to do something a little different with my flash embedding on an HTML page. I added an option to the right click context menu to toggle between two scales modes: **noscale** and **exactfit**. This works when I run the swf as a standalone but not within an HTML page. Does anyone have any ideas if there a way to embed a swf and dynamically change the scale mode? Perhaps embedding with 100% width and height? However I tried that and it breaks the embed javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var params = {};
    params.scale = "exactfit"
    var flashVars = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF("UserInterfaceStagingCR.swf", "myContent", "1440", "900", "9", null, flashVars, params);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this post about resizing a SWF set to 100% width/height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952732/resize-an-swf-when-loading-it-with-swfobject/1005254#1005254).

But if you want to switch from `noScale` to `exactFit` (and vice-versa), you probably need to edit the `param` node in your JavaScript.

I've never actually tried it (I'm not sure if it will work), but here's what I'd experiment with:

```
function setScaleMode(mode){

    var paramNodes = document.getElementsByTagName("param");

    for(var i=0, len=paramNodes.length; i<len; i++){
        var node = paramNodes[i];
        if(node.name === "scale"){
            //switch to whatever scale mode you want to use.
            node.value = mode;
            //exit loop
            return;
        }
    }

}

var params = { scale: "exactfit" };
var flashVars = {};

swfobject.embedSWF("UserInterfaceStagingCR.swf", "myContent", "1440", "900", "9", false, flashVars, params);
```

(Of course, this code would need to be modified if you have multiple SWFs on a page.)

Then have your ActionScript invoke the JavaScript via ExternalInterface:

```
ExternalInterface.call("setScaleMode", "noscale");
```